# java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out on WSO2 Identity Server OAuth Token Validation

Tags: java, wso2, apache-axis, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

When trying to OAuth Token Validation of LDAP user from WSO2 ESB to WSO2 IS the following error has occured at ESB some times.

```
    {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender} -  Unable to sendViaPost to url
    [https://identityserver.com/services/OAuth2TokenValidationService] 
    {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender} java.net.SocketTimeoutException: 
    Read timed out
```

The OAuth Token validation succesfully worked First few times after server start and after the above error occures.

What will be the reason for above error?  How can fix this?

**Update**

The identity server logs shows the following error at the same time.

```
 TID: [0] [IS] [2013-12-19 05:04:52,904] ERROR {java.lang.Class} - 
 Access Denied. Failed authorization attempt to access service 'OAuth2TokenValidationService' operation 'validate' by 'LDAP/admin' {java.lang.Class}
    TID: [0] [IS] [2013-12-19 05:04:52,904] ERROR {org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine} -  Access Denied. {org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine}
    org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Access Denied.
        at org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.module.handler.AuthorizationHandler.doAuthorization(AuthorizationHandler.java:124)
        at org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.module.handler.AuthorizationHandler.invoke(AuthorizationHandler.java:88)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invokeHandler(Phase.java:340)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:313)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:261)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:167)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
```

Why this Access Denied error some times. It succesfully login some other times.??

Answer (score 1):

According to the error, it seems to be that ESB can not send the message to following url. Sometimes this service takes much time to response back to the ESB (more than 30s). Then we can guess,  issue may be in the WSO2IS side..  Could you can see any error or any logs in WSO2IS side? If not, could you enable debug logs in the WSO2IS and see. you can use log4j.properties file for that.  If it is late to response, by looking at the time stamp in the log4j logs, we can get some idea on where the bottleneck has happened.

> https://identityserver.com/services/OAuth2TokenValidationService

Comment: The user name/password that you configure in the OAuth mediator,  is used to login to server and access the "OAuth2TokenValidationService".  User/password,  must be an admin users (user in admin role or some permission to access this service) in the WSO2IS server. It is not sure why this is not working for some times..  Are you doing any load test?

Comment: The issue is like: We used two user storages ( Primary and ldap ). "OAuth2TokenValidationService" configured to use a admin user in primary. It some times tried to login as ldap/username and produces the acess denied error. I think it is a bug in the OAuth2TokenValidationService when there is more than one user storages.

Comment: you means that same user (user with same user name) exists in the both user store (primary and LDAP)? Could you please verify?

Comment: Only one user exists.